# How to set metadata for AVFileTypeMPEG4 file via AVAssetExportSession?

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I'm trying to use `AVAssetExportSession` to set the metadata of a `AVFileTypeMPEG4` type file,but it 
doesn't work,if I change the file type to `AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie`,it works.But I need mp4 file,I can't find any document say `AVFileTypeMPEG4` file can not be set metadata,Has anyone set meta successfully?
Here is the code that I used:

```
NSMutableArray *metadata = [NSMutableArray array];
    AVMutableMetadataItem *metaItem = [AVMutableMetadataItem metadataItem];
    metaItem.key = AVMetadataCommonKeySource;
    metaItem.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon;
    metaItem.value = @"Test metadata";
    [metadata addObject:metaItem];
AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:composition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
        exportSession.metadata = metadata;
        exportSession.audioMix = audioMix;
        exportSession.videoComposition = videoComposition;
        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;//AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
        NSString *outputFilePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testMetadata.mp4"];
        exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputFilePath];
        [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) {
                    //todo
                }else{
                    //todo
                }
            });
        }];
```

Comment: What is the error message, I just did a test which worked for me.

Comment: @gabbler Exporting the video is success,but the video has no metadata

Comment: How did you find there is no metadata? what kind of metadata is missing? Is there no metadata or is it just the "Test metadata" missing?

Comment: @gabbler After exporting finish,I create a new AVAsset by `outputFilePath`,and I check the AVAsset's metadata,it returns nil,the "Test metadata" is missing.

Comment: @gabbler If I change the `outputFileType ` to `AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie `,the asset's `metadata` has "Test metadata"

Comment: How did you get the meta data? Using mdls?

Comment: @gabbler The `AVAsset`'s property `metadata`

Comment: Usually not setting any metadata resulting in saving all original metadata from the raw file, however, If you don't set any metadata for type AVFileTypeMPEG4, the exported file's metadata is nil. So my guessing is you can't.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with

```
    metaItem.key = AVMetadataiTunesMetadataKeyDescription;
    metaItem.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceiTunes;
```

tried the other keyspaces but only itunes worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Apple filters metadata depending on the output type. They don't consider iTunes metadata valid for MPEG4 output, so they strip it.

Some options:

- Use AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie > MOV is closely related to MP4, and is often compatible. This depends on what you are looking to do.
- Try other types (some people report success with the MPV type)
- use a library to write custom data/atoms (mp4v2 works for example). Lots of work, but the only real way to achieve it.